# Get sheet by name using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am writing some data into an Excel file, but I don’t know how to adjust the code in order to be able to control which sheet I am writing into:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename)
active_ws = wb.active
```

Instead of `wb.active`, how can I say something like `Sheets('Data')` (this is how the VBA syntax would look like...)?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

You should use `wb[sheetname]`

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb2 = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws4 = wb2["New Title"]
```

PS:
You should check if your sheet in  sheet names `wb.sheetnames`

```
print(wb2.sheetnames)
['Sheet2', 'New Title', 'Sheet1']
```

Answer (score 16):

```
import openpyxl

n = 0
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('D:\excel.xlsx')
sheets = wb.sheetnames
ws = wb[sheets[n]]
```

The reference:
*[How to switch between sheets in Excel openpyxl Python to make changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45756731/how-to-switch-between-sheets-in-excel-openpyxl-python-to-make-changes?rq=1)*

Answer (score 1):

Fix your `openpyxl` version. Upgrading from 2.3.2 to 2.4.10 will fix this issue. Do this:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org openpyxl==2.4.10
```

Answer (score 1):

The above solution works but just to point out that the excel file should be "Excel Workbook (.xlsx)" and not the "Strict Open XML Spreadsheet (.xlsx)"

```
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file.xlsx)
sheet = workbook[sheet_name]
```