# Set the active sheet with openpyxl

Tags: python-2.7, openpyxl

http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/_modules/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.html?highlight=set%20active%20sheet

The documentation shows a Workbook object has an `active` property:

```
@property
def active(self):
    """Get the currently active sheet"""
    return self._sheets[self._active_sheet_index]

@active.setter
def active(self, value):
    """Set the active sheet"""
    self._active_sheet_index = value
```

If `wb = openpyxl.Workbook()` is calling `wb.active`, it gives the title of the default first worksheet, which is `Sheet`.

Say I create another sheet, `ws1 = wb.create_sheet('another sheet')`, how do I **"set"** this to be the active sheet?

The documentation shows there is an active "setter" also called active. It takes an extra argument, an integer index value.

How come `wb.active(1)` does not work? Am I not calling the function with

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python openpyxl select sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814050/python-openpyxl-select-sheet)

Comment: The link is broken: *"This page does not exist yet"*

Comment: Something seems to be missing after *"calling the function with"*. Or is "with" literal?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Later versions of `openpyxl` allow the active sheet to be set directly:

```py
wb.active = wb['sheet_name']
```

Use the following in demonstration:

```py
# Set Active Sheet
wb.active = wb['charlie']
```

---

For earlier versions, a demonstration to save the workbook, allowing any chosen process to be verified:

This is a different approach of setting active sheet in workbook by sheet name. There are similar answers (*[Get sheet by name using openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814050/openpyxl-get-sheet-by-name)* and others did not have enough detail for me to understand this functionality).

The [Manipulating a workbook in memory](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5/tutorial.html#manipulating-a-workbook-in-memory) tutorial is the place to start and under the answer I have used this tutorial to demonstrate there is no active sheet name, it is actually the sheet at the active index. A different sheet will become active if adding or deleting a sheet changes the sheet at the index position.

Initially I thought `.create_sheet` made the sheet active, but then I realised I had only created the sheet at the active sheet index which happened to be 0. The index can be set to a value greater than the number of sheets and the docs also contain a note that "If the sheet set to active is hidden return the next visible sheet or None".

#### Verbose short answer

```
for i, s in enumerate(wb.sheetnames):
    if s == 'charlie':
        break
wb.active = i
```

Feel free to improve this answer.

#### Demonstration

```
py
```

Interactive session:

```py
Python 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> # http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5/tutorial.html#create-a-workbook
>>> from openpyxl import Workbook
>>> wb = Workbook()
>>> print(wb.sheetnames)
['Sheet']
>>>
>>> print(wb.active)
<Worksheet "Sheet">
>>> ws = wb.active
>>> ws.title = "alpha"
>>>
>>> ws = wb.create_sheet('bravo')
>>> print(wb.sheetnames)
['alpha', 'bravo']
>>> print(wb.active)
<Worksheet "alpha">
>>>
>>> ws = wb.create_sheet('charlie',0)  # insert at index 0
>>> print(wb.sheetnames)
['charlie', 'alpha', 'bravo']
>>> print(wb.active)
<Worksheet "charlie">
>>>
>>>
>>> wb.active = 1
>>> print(wb.active)
<Worksheet "alpha">
>>>
>>> wb.active = 2
>>> print(wb.active)
<Worksheet "bravo">
>>>
>>> wb.active = 0
>>> print(wb.active)
<Worksheet "charlie">
>>>
>>> wb.active = 3
>>> print(wb.active)
None
>>>
>>> ws = wb.create_sheet(index=0)  # insert at index
>>> print(wb.active)
<Worksheet "bravo">
>>> print(wb.sheetnames)
['Sheet', 'charlie', 'alpha', 'bravo']
>>>
>>>
>>> ws_active = wb.get_sheet_by_name('charlie')
<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function get_sheet_by_name (Use wb[sheetname]).
>>> ws_active = wb['charlie']
>>> print(wb.active)
<Worksheet "bravo">
>>> ws4 = wb["charlie"] # from https://stackoverflow.com/a/36814135/4539999
>>> print(wb.active)
<Worksheet "bravo">
>>>
>>> # Set Active Sheet
>>> for i, s in enumerate(wb.sheetnames):
...     if s == 'charlie':
...         break
...
>>> wb.active = i
>>>
>>> # Confirm Active Sheet
>>> print(wb.active)
<Worksheet "charlie">
>>>
>>> # Open workbook to verify
>>> wb.save("Demo.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thanks. I looked into the code for this, and that is where I found the @ type function. We came to the same conclusion about the syntax. =)

Comment: Issue logged: `https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/1033/active-sheet-index-not-updated-on-sheet`

Comment: henry434's one-liner consistent with other packages works

Comment: No, see comment `active_sheet = wb['sheet name']` doesn't set anything.

Comment: You have a bug in your demonstration. Setting `ws_active` but printing `ws.active`.

Comment: See comment [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41556378/openpyxl-set-active-sheet/50117733#comment126563847_50117733) ie using it doesn't set active, actually `print(wb.active)`

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't look like a typical function call, but to use the "setter" you would write:

`wb.active = 1`

Which "eats" the 1 =) and changes the active sheet.

Comment: This has tripped me up recently. The Workbook object uses `.__setattr__()` to intercept the assignment (and hence change the logic of it), and `.__getattr__()` to return something else when the property is read. This really is bad practice but I guess we just can't have it all...

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
sheets = wb.get_sheet_names()
for i in sheets:
    if i == 'xyz':
        wb.active = i
        break
```

Or you can simply do

```
xyz_sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('xyz')
wb.active = xyz_sheet
```

The workbook (i.e., *wb*) has the *xyz* sheet active now.

Comment: Function get_sheet_by_name was only included in https://stackoverflow.com/a/50117733/4539999 demonstration to highlight it is depreciated.

Comment: Isn't it more concise to write (taking into account get_sheet_by_name is deprecated): 
 wb.active = wb['xyz']

Answer (score 0):

For reference, another useful way to do it - particularly when you want to call the sheet by its name:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path/to/your/spreadsheet)
worksheet_names = wb.sheetnames # this variable is presented as a list, so we can manipulate it accordingly, but finding the index number using the name.
sheet_index = worksheet_names.index(<name of your target sheet>) # this will return the index number where your worksheet resides.  It should be mentioned that this sheet name must exist in the worksheet_names list variable
wb.active = sheet_index # this will activate the worksheet by index
```

You should now be working in the sheet of your choice, but the benefit here is that you have been able to call the sheet by name rather than by number.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the tab, you can write one line:

```
book.active = book.sheetnames.index('YourSheetName')
```

Answer (score -2):

This is the simplest way to set an active worksheet by name:

```
active_sheet = wb['sheet name']
```

Comment: This doesn't set anything.

Comment: Are you putting the name of the sheet in? Eg: Sheet1

Comment: No, it's just wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50117733/4539999 and verify with the demonstration.