# How to switch between sheets in Excel openpyxl Python to make changes

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Consider:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('D:\excel.xlsx')
wb.get_sheet_names()
```

After this, I can see the worksheets (85) that the Excel file has. Now I want to go into each sheet, edit data in 2-3 cells (which is same for all the sheets) and then save the file.

Comment: You'll get more help if you do at least try to write some code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iteration over Worksheets, Rows, Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974450/iteration-over-worksheets-rows-columns)

Answer (score 7):

In your case I see the easiest is probably

```
import openpyxl

n = 0
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('D:\excel.xlsx')
sheets = wb.sheetnames
ws = wb[sheets[n]]
```

Where **n** is the sheetnumber (0 is the first). Put that in a loop and increase **n** when you want to change the sheet.

Answer (score 2):

When mentioning the path, use [forward slash](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forward_slash#Noun) rather than [backslash](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/backslash#Noun).

#### Get all sheet names. Find the sheetwise maximum row and column in a particular sheet

```
import openpyxl

workBook = load_workbook(filename='D:/excel.xlsx')
sheets = workBook.sheetnames
i = 1
for s_name in sheets:
    print(s_name)
    sheet = workBook[s_name]
    m_row = sheet.max_row
    m_col = sheet.max_column
    print(m_row)
    print(m_col)
```

Comment: What is variable `i` for?