# How do I edit this code so it extracts data from a specific sheet from multiple excel files to display in a separate file

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have python code that will take data from multiple excel files and display the selected data in a separate file for further analysis. It works:

```
import os
import openpyxl

folder = 'D:\My Documents\Code\Data'
output_file = 'D:\My Documents\Code\Data\masterfile.xlsx'

output_wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
output_sheet = output_wb.active
output_sheet.title = 'masterfile'

cells = ['A2', 'B2', 'C2']

for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    if filename.endswith('.xlsx'):
        filename = os.path.join(folder, filename)
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
        values = [workbook.active[cell].value for cell in cells]
        output_sheet.append(values)

output_wb.save(output_file)
```

However, it can only take code from the active sheet... Which means if I want to take data from Sheet2 I have to save all the excel files (hundreds of them) with Sheet2 as the active sheet otherwise it wont work. So I thought I would try and set the active sheet in the code itself but it does not work. I have only been learning Python for a month and I am not a coder by trade, but a scientist working with a lot of biological data. This codes does not work and I need help to fix it.

```
import os
import openpyxl

folder = 'D:\My Documents\Code\Data'
output_file = 'D:\My Documents\Code\Data\masterfile.xlsx'

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

output_wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
output_sheet = output_wb.active
output_sheet.title = 'masterfile'

cells = ['A2', 'B2', 'C2']

for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    if filename.endswith('.xlsx'):
        filename = os.path.join(folder, filename)
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
        workbook.active = workbook.sheetnames.index('Sheet2')
        values = [workbook.active[cell].value for cell in cells]
        output_sheet.append(values)

output_wb.save(output_file)
```

I tried setting the active worksheet as Sheet2 but it only takes data from the active sheet the original excel files are stored under.

I have tried the suggestions in these links but to no avail:

[Set the active sheet with openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41556378/set-the-active-sheet-with-openpyxl)
[How to switch between sheets in Excel openpyxl Python to make changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45756731/how-to-switch-between-sheets-in-excel-openpyxl-python-to-make-changes?rq=1)
[Get sheet by name using openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814050/get-sheet-by-name-using-openpyxl)

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: How about `workbook.active = workbook.sheetnames['Sheet2']` ?  The way it done here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36814135/2055998 (the 1st link on your list).

Comment: I cannot get any of those suggestions to work with the code I have so I guess I need to do a full re-write.

Comment: What happens after you replace your `workbook.active = workbook.sheetnames.index('Sheet2')` with the the statement I provided?

Comment: I get the error: 

xtractor Specific Sheet.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\My Documents\Code\Excel Data Extractor Specific Sheet.py", line 17, in <module>
    workbook.active = workbook.sheetnames['Sheet2']
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: I think it's even simpler. `workbook.active = workbook['Sheet2']`  Try this.

Comment: When I do that I get this error: 

AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 287, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError("Worksheet {0} does not exist.".format(key))

I wonder if I am missing a module?

Comment: Do you have the latest `openpyxl`?

Comment: Yes, I upgraded to the version dated March 11th 2024

Comment: small correction, the latest release was March 11 2023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not missing any modules

A quick tutorial on selecting worksheets

The active sheet is the sheet that had focus when the workbook was saved and can be accessed as

```
sheet = wb.active
```

where 'wb' is the Openpyxl workbook object. This is also for selecting the default sheet when creating a new workbook.

If you want any other Sheet in the workbook then you can select it by name;

```
sheet = wb['<sheet name>']
```

where `<sheet name>` is the name (aka '**title**' in Openpyxl) of the sheet, noting the names are case sensitive. `wb['sheet1']` will return an error if the sheet name is 'Sheet1'.

Further; the *names* of the sheets are contained in the list `wb.sheetnames` i.e. this is a list of the names of the sheets only, as strings. 
Therefore you could select every sheet in the workbook by;

```py
for sheetname in wb.sheetnames:
    sheet = wb[sheetname]
    ...
```

but would probably only use this method if you want to filter sheets selected by the title.

The actual *worksheet objects* are held in the list `wb.worksheets`. 
If you want to work on every worksheet in the workbook you can loop through all the Sheets by;

```
for sheet in wb.worksheets:
    print(sheet.title)
    # do something with the worksheet object 'sheet' having 'title' ...
```

therefore with this list a sheet can also be selected using its index as;

```
sheet = wb.worksheets[X]
```

where X is the index of the sheet you require.

The Sheets are generally listed in the order they appear in the workbook.

Comment: Thank you so, so, so, so much. This helped me so much. My gratitude to you is eternal!