# How to load a workbook and at the same time go to a specific sheet? using Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I already have a code to load a workbook and add a new sheet as well.
How can I transfer to that new sheet added after loading the workbook? I am using openpyxl

```
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('Sample File.xlsx')
workbook.create_sheet('Sample Sheet')
workbook.save(filename='Sample File.xlsx')
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Just catch the sheet thrown by create_sheet:

```
ws = workbook.create_sheet('Sample Sheet')
```

"ws" above contains the created sheet. Alternatively, you can load any sheet in a workbook using:

```
ws = workbook['Sample Sheet']
```

Comment: get_sheet_by_name is already not available with the openpyxl version I am using which is 3.0.9, what can be an alternative for this?

Comment: Yes it's been a while since I used openpyxl. It might have been deprecated. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814050/openpyxl-get-sheet-by-name